# "ASFUnicodeAttribute" problem when printing wma song titles with mutagen

Tags: mutagen, wma, asf

Hey guys I recently started working with mutagen and I'm facing a very annoying problem.
Let´s say I´m trying to print the title of a  wma file with mutagen:

```
from mutagen.asf import ASF

song=r"C:\Users\j2the\Music\The One and Only\Rammstein\Made In Germany\03 Keine Lust.wma"

song_wma=ASF(song)
print(song_wma["Title"])
```

The code may work fine, but when printing the title of the wma file, python always adds the extension [ASFUnicodeAttribute...] to the actual filename:

```
[ASFUnicodeAttribute('Keine Lust')]
```

Is there any way to have the code return only the actual title of the song?
Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I eventually figured out the solution myself. It's actually very simple. All you have to do is iterate over the title tag and voilà: You´re left with only the title of the song:

```
for e in song_wma["Title"]:
    print(e)
```

Outcome:

```
Keine Lust
```

Answer (score 0):

And by the way, if anybody is loooking for an easy tagging module for mp3, wma, flac files etc., I would recommend the `tinytag` module, which is much less complicated to work with than the mutagen module. Just my personal opinion though.